# Java Streams TakeUntil 100 Elements filtered/collected

Tags: java, functional-programming, stream, java-stream

I want to use streams like:

```
List<String> result = myArr
    .stream()
    .filter(line -> !"foo".equals(line))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but stop the filtering as soon as I have maximum 100 Elements ready to be collected. How can I achieve this without filtering all and calling `subList(100, result.size())` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `limit` **after** `filter`:

```
List<String> result = myArr
    .stream()
    .filter(line -> !"foo".equals(line))
    .limit(100) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will stop the stream after 100 items have been found after filtering ([`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) is a short-circuiting stream operation).